# Combining Context and Token Use Cases into Generic ABC

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I have a basic ABC here:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class StreamingService(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def search_one(self, q):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def supports_url(self, url):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_title_from_url(self, url):
        pass
```

Problem is some of the classes that extend StreamingService use a *context* for their calls i.e.

```
class Context:
  def __enter__():
    ...

  def __exit__():
    ...

def search_one(self, context, q):
  ...

context = Context()
client.search_one(context, "query")
```

And other classes only require a string *token*.

```
def search_one(self, token, q):
  ...

token = "abcdef012345"
client.search_one(token, "query")
```

I could have each function in the ABC require a "context" var that leaves it up to the subclass owner to interpret. However, this feels like sloppy code design that isn't clear on its intention and breaks the standard definition of a "context".

What are some design patterns I could use to fuse these two use cases and make it clear to anyone else using the code?

**The ultimate goal would be to homogenize how developers interact with each streaming service to reduce confusion and the need to look up documentation for each individual service.**

Suggestions outside the realm of code design and into how I'm interacting with the APIs themselves is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to turn each StreamingService into its own ContextManager. Each one requires an ‘**enter**’ and ‘**exit**’ but the implementation is up to the subclass.

Subclasses with clients initialize and close their client on enter/exit. Those that use tokens send a request for their token on ‘**enter**’ and do nothing on ‘**exit**’.